# Do we have any phoenix gen socket client in Erlang

Tags: erlang, phoenix-framework

I am trying to listen to a phoenix channel from Erlang Node.

Do we have any Phoenix Gen Socket Client written in Erlang? I found one written in Elixir (https://github.com/Aircloak/phoenix_gen_socket_client) but not Erlang :(

Please help

Answer (score 1):

You can use Elixir dependencies directly in Erlang. See https://www.rebar3.org/docs/using-available-plugins#section-elixir-dependencies

Comment: I tried following this link: https://www.rebar3.org/docs/using-available-plugins#section-elixir-dependencies
1- I added the plugins, hooks, overlay and modified vm.args
then I followed - https://www.rebar3.org/docs/releases#section-deployable
2- rebar3 release -d false
3- rebar3 as prod tar
4- mkdir myrel
5- mv myrel-0.1.0.tar.gz myrel/
6- cd myrel
7- tar -zxvf myrel-0.1.0.tar.gz
8- bin/myrel console

I still get undefined error. Any help would be much much appreciated.